# Proof verification : Inequality involving moment generating function (MGF)

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

The problem is as follows.

[image: Problem]

My solution : Let $t \geq 0$ be arbitrary. Then

$E(e^{tX})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx}dF(x) \geq \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tx}dF(x) \geq \int_{0}^{\infty} dF(x)=P\{X \geq 0\}$

Hence, $P\{X \geq 0\} \leq \inf \{E(e^{tX}); t \geq 0\} \leq E(e^{0 \cdot X})=1$

I'd appreciate if anyone checks it and tell me whether there's any technicalities that I may have missed. Do I need to show that $P\{X \geq 0\} \leq \inf \{E(e^{tX}); t \geq 0\}$ explicitly (by contradiction, for example)? Or is it fine to imply it directly?

Answer (score 0):

The proof seems fine.

You have proven that $\forall t \ge 0, E(e^{tX}) \ge P\{X \ge 0\}$, which implies
$$\inf\{ E(e^{tX}):t \ge 0\} \ge P\{ X \ge 0\}$$

Comment: Everything is fine except for one small thing. $\int _0 ^{\infty} dF$ is not a standard notation when densities are not known to exist. Since integrals over single points need not be 0 you should write $\int_{[0,\infty)} dF$.

Comment: Thank you. @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the technical correction. Indeed, there is no other information on $F$ is given apart from that it is a distribution function.